# Mysql Update, 2 databases

Tags: mysql, database, date, set

I have 2 MYSQL tables and when I pick up dates from table A which contains only 1 column and lets say 10 rows with dates

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM A");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And after I want to UPDATE another table B with using this dates from table A            `mysql_query("UPDATE B SET something='1' WHERE name='".$row['name']."'")`
So i need to update the second table, but its updating just once with first date from table A, and other 9 its ignoring. So my question is, how to make updating of second table with each date from 1 table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a the updates in a loop. After executing your query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM A");
```

and verifying that it has succeeded (make sure `$result` is not null), instead of fetching one row, use a loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // perform calculations & assignments with the $row elements
    $result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE B SET something='1'
                            WHERE name='".$row['name']."'");
    if(! $result2){
         echo "update failed";
    }
    // Any other stuff you need to do
}
```

---

Alternatively:

If the `something` in the update is the same for all the rows, you can change your first query to give you a coma-separated string of names:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT("'",GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR "','"),"'")
                       AS all_names FROM A");
```

This way, you receive only one row, and you can then use it in your second query:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE B SET something='1'
                        WHERE name IN (".$row['name'].")");
```